# Почему не заполняется DataTable?

Tags: c#

Так выглядит метод, который возвращает datatable после выполнения процедуры:

```
public static DataTable GetTours(string fromCity, string toCountry, string departureDate, int amountNihgts, int amountAdults)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            string sql = "[dbo].[GetToursLits]";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add("@FromCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                command.Parameters["@FromCity"].Value = fromCity;
                command.Parameters.Add("@ToCountry", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                command.Parameters["@ToCountry"].Value = toCountry;
                command.Parameters.Add("@departureDate", SqlDbType.Date);
                command.Parameters["@departureDate"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(departureDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                command.Parameters.Add("@amountNihgts", SqlDbType.Int);
                command.Parameters["@amountNihgts"].Value = amountNihgts;
                command.Parameters.Add("@amountAdults", SqlDbType.Int);
                command.Parameters["@amountAdults"].Value = amountAdults;

                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    connection.Close();
                }                    
                return dataTable;
            }
        }
    }
```

При его вызове он возвращает пустую DataTable.
Процедура выглядит так:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetToursLits](@fromCity nvarchar, @toCountry nvarchar, @departureDate date, @amountNihgts int, @amountAdults int)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM dbo.Tours 
END
```

Если выполнить код с Begin до End, то в Massege появится таблица с данными. 
Может с процедурой что-то не так?

Comment: `FromCity != fromCity`, `ToCountry != toCountry`? И ещё у вас опечатки в слове `Nihgts`.

Comment: `@fromCity nvarchar` - у вас параметры обрезаются до одного символа. Задайте им длину.

Comment: И ещё замечание по коду: DateTime нужно парсить где-то выше по коду, а в этот метод передавать уже готовый тип. Или, по крайней мере, делать парсинг сразу при входе в метод с выбросом исключения в случае ошибки.

Comment: `connection.Open()` в данном случае не обязателен - DataAdapter сам его откроет. `connection.Close()` тоже не нужен: он закроется при выходе из блока `using`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо большое. Все работает как надо теперь. А если, например, я вызову этот метод раз 20, то у меня создастся 20 процедур "GetToursLists"?

Comment: Хранимка создается при помощи `create procedure ...`. А когда вы используете `"[dbo].[GetToursLits]"` - это просто _вызов_ процедуры. | Оформите ответ с правильным кодом (и потом примите его).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря [Alexander Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov) разобрался:

```
public static DataTable GetTours(string fromCity, string toCountry, string departureDate, int amountNihgts, int amountAdults)
    {
        DateTime departureDateParsed = DateTime.ParseExact(departureDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            string sql = "[dbo].[GetToursLists]";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add("@fromCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
                command.Parameters["@fromCity"].Value = fromCity;
                command.Parameters.Add("@toCountry", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
                command.Parameters["@toCountry"].Value = toCountry;
                command.Parameters.Add("@departureDate", SqlDbType.Date);
                command.Parameters["@departureDate"].Value = departureDateParsed;
                command.Parameters.Add("@amountNights", SqlDbType.Int);
                command.Parameters["@amountNights"].Value = amountNihgts;
                command.Parameters.Add("@amountAdults", SqlDbType.Int);
                command.Parameters["@amountAdults"].Value = amountAdults;
                using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }

                return dataTable;
            }
        }
    }
```